# Verify that $T(f):=\int_{-1}^0 f(x)dx-\int_{0}^1 f(x)dx$ is a bounded functional$ and find its norm

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Let ($C[-1,1], \lVert  \cdot \rVert _\infty)$ be a space of continuous functions on $[-1,1]$ with sup norm. Verify that $T(f):=\int_{-1}^0 f(x)dx-\int_{0}^1 f(x)dx$ is a functional and determinate if it is bounded. If so, find its norm.

Comment: Hint: $f(x)=1$ for $x<0$ and $-1$ for $x\geq 0$ is not a continuous function but it can be apprximated by continuous functions. (Answer $\|T\|=2$).